# ARIMA with more than one attribute python

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, arima

Here, I have a dataset with two attributes. I have totally 200 days and each day have `TotalTransactionNumber` and `Price` attributes such as:

```
    Day, Price,TotalTransactionNumber
    10/18/2015 0:00,262.9,118916
    10/19/2015 0:00,264.42,151128
    10/20/2015 0:00,270.22,147335
    10/21/2015 0:00,267.33,149446
    10/22/2015 0:00,274.41,146556
    10/23/2015 0:00,277.46,142066
    10/24/2015 0:00,282.66,140943
    10/25/2015 0:00,283.07,131191
```

Here, I am trying to use ARIMA but I do not know how to use it. In this case, I am trying to guess price values.
If it is only price, this code snippet will work but I do not know how to modify it.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import pandas as pd

series = pd.read_csv('prices.csv')
X = series.values
train, test = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(5,1,0))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
    print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: get a grasp about the `exog` argument of `ARIMA`.

---

As far as I can tell, you got the code from this very good tutorial:

```
https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/
```

Well, ARIMA is a statistical method to analyse and forecast time series. As such, at first it should only deal with data from the time series itself. But, there's another model called ARIMAX, that deals with exogenous data that could complement what can be observed through the main time series.

In the case of `statsmodels`, `ARIMAX` is just a specific case of `ARIMA` when the parameter `exog` is set.

You should try playing around with that, taking care of any "hidden" correlation between `Price` and `TotalTransactionNumber`.